# Is it possible to access a Module from within a haml file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

I'd like to create sort my helpers into sub-modules, in order to make the code cleaner. For example, I'd like to implement something like this:

```
= UI.spawn_component(UI.alert, UI.error, "message")
```

I already tried just creating a module in my helper module like this:

```
module StyleguideHelper
  module UI
    def spawn_component(user, type)
      return user
    end
  end
end
```

And I also tried to create the module in a different file and require it from my helper file. Both of those didn't work.

Comment: One cannot call regular functions from modules that way. It would not work even in `irb`. `spawn_component` must be a module function to call it like this.

Comment: I tried making `spawn_component` a module function (by defining it as `self.spawn_component`, right?), but it gives me this error: `uninitialized constant ActionView::CompiledTemplates::UI`

Comment: Have you tried `StyleGuideHelper::UI.spawn_component(StyleGuideHelper::UI.alert, StyleGuideHelper::UI.error, "message")`?

Comment: Yes, same error, just with StyleGuideHelper.

Comment: `::StyleGuideHelper::UI.spawn_component(...)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make sure that the file is named correctly so that autoloading works correctly. If the module is called `StyleguideHelper` then the file must be named   `styleguide_helper.rb`. I would place this file in `app/helpers` unless you've setup lib for autoloading. Define your modules in that file like this:

```
module StyleguideHelper
  module UI
    def self.spawn_component(user, type)
      return user
    end
  end
end
```

You should then be able to use the helper in your view like this:

```
= StyleguideHelper::UI.spawn_component(user, type)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that worked perfectly! Also, regarding the file naming: Is this true for any module?

Comment: Yes, this is true for any module or class that need to be auto loaded by Rails.